# Internationalization of dynamic content in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internationalization, angular-i18n

Angular.io describes the i18n tag as follows:

> The Angular i18n attribute marks translatable content. Place it on
>   every element tag whose fixed text is to be translated.

So my question is this. What if I have an element whose content is ***dynamic?*** Take for example this below table that shows a list of assets. The column, "Description" needs to be in some cases English, and in some cases some other language.

```
    <table class="asset-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-timeon">Time On</th>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-timeoff">Time Off</th>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-asset">Asset</th>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-description">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="showAssets">
        <tr *ngFor="let asset of pageItems">
          <td>{{asset.timeon}}</td>
          <td>{{asset.timeoff}}</td>
          <td>{{asset.assetlabel}}</td>
          <td i18n>{{asset.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I was thinking something like this:

```
    <table class="asset-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-timeon">Time On</th>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-timeoff">Time Off</th>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-asset">Asset</th>
          <th i18n="@@alarm-list-description">Description</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody *ngIf="showAssets">
        <tr *ngFor="let asset of pageItems">
          <td>{{asset.timeon}}</td>
          <td>{{asset.timeoff}}</td>
          <td>{{asset.assetlabel}}</td>
          <td i18n="@@{{asset.description}}">{{asset.description}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

...but I was mistaken. Any suggestions?

Comment: Angular i18n is static, not dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the i18n value is an ID, so it would always be static.

Second, as far as translating content that changes, the only success I have had is a workaround using [NgSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) in the template.

In this example, `thingStatus` is your variable, and its possible values are 'good', 'bad', and 'unknown'. All of these would each be a separate translation item, with its own i18n ID value.

Obviously, this would fail if `thingStatus` could have an unmanageable number of possibilities.

```
    <div [ngSwitch]="thingStatus">
        <p *ngSwitchCase="good" i18n="status_good>Good</p>
        <p *ngSwitchCase="bad" i18n="status_bad>Bad</p>
        <p *ngSwitchCase="unknown" i18n="status_unknown>Unknown</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this construction

```
<span
  i18n="status text|Status text@@statusText"
>{
  asset.statusLangCode, select,

  bad {Bad}
  good {Good}

  other {Unknown}
}</span>
```

And in translation file there will be generated a construct like this (target is added manually)

```
<source>{VAR_SELECT, select, good {Good} bad {Bad} other {Unknown}}</source>
<target>{VAR_SELECT, select, good {Хороший} bad {Плохой} other {Неизвестный}}</target>
```

For more info see https://angular.io/guide/i18n#translate-select

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your backend service returns known possible values, you can do the following:

```
const values = ['admin', 'teacher', 'librarian']
```

Add the translated values to `sv_SE.json` given the previous values as keys

```
role: {
  "admin": "admin",
  "teacher": "lärare",
  "librarian": "Bibliotekarie"
}
```

Call the translation in your `app.component.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
{{ ('role.' + value) | translate }}
</div>
```